# Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'System.Drawing.Point' to 'System.Drawing.Size'

Tags: vb.net, strict, option-strict

After i tried to optimize my code with option Strict ON i get many errors at least one is left.

i've created the Variable *MoveForm_MousePosition as Point* = System.drawing.point

```
    Imports System.Drawing
    Public MoveForm_MousePosition As Point

Private Sub lblYaple_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles lblYaple.MouseDown
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            MoveForm = True
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.NoMove2D
            MoveForm_MousePosition = e.Location
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Sub lblYaple_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles lblYaple.MouseMove
        If MoveForm Then Me.Location = Me.Location + (e.Location - MoveForm_MousePosition)
    End Sub
```

In this Line

If MoveForm Then Me.Location = Me.Location + (e.Location - **MoveForm_MousePosition**)

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'System.Drawing.Point' to 'System.Drawing.Size'

can't understand, me.location and e.location and MoveForm_MousePostions should be
System.Drawing.Point why comes this error up?

Comment: Try this? `Me.Location = Me.Location + New Point(e.Location - MoveForm_MousePosition)`

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the [MSDN documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.op_subtraction%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the RHS parameter type of the point subtraction operator is [Size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
'LHS (point)  RHS (size)
(e.Location - MoveForm_MousePosition)
```

And as observed, you cannot convert a point structure to a size structure. So one way to fix this is to create a new point structure like this:

```
Me.Location = New Point(
    (Me.Location.X + (e.Location.X - MoveForm_MousePosition.X)),
    (Me.Location.Y + (e.Location.Y - MoveForm_MousePosition.Y))
)
```

Comment: @RichardDark If it works, then you should mark the answer by clicking the checkmark to remove it from the unanswered list and acknowledge Mr K's effort.